# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types in constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, dbnull

I need to add into the list one object CompanyDetails, so I get data from my database, and load it into constructor.

```
result.Add(new CompanyDetails() { 
    Name = dr["name"].ToString(), 
    City = dr["city"].ToString(), 
    StreetName = dr["streetName"].ToString(), 
    StreetNr = Convert.ToInt32(dr["apartmentNr"]), 
    Tax = int.Parse(dr["TAX"].ToString() )});
```

`StreetNr` and `Tax` can have null value. And when I'm trying to run it i get the error:

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

How can I fix it? I know that normally I should check if tax or streetNr equals DBNull or not, but I don't know how I can do it in this case.

this is class CompanyDetails:

```
public class CompanyDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public int? StreetNr { get; set; }
    public int? Tax { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Tax = dr["TAX"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)dr["TAX"]
```

That will check if it's `null`, if it is, it sets the `int` value to `0`, otherwise it assigns the integer value.

Applying that to your code:

```
result.Add(new CompanyDetails() { 
    Name = dr["name"].ToString(), 
    City = dr["city"].ToString(), 
    StreetName = dr["streetName"].ToString(), 
    StreetNr = dr["apartmentNr"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)dr["apartmentNr"]
    Tax = dr["TAX"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)dr["TAX"]
    )});
```

EDIT:
In case `StreetNr` and `Tax` are already of type `int?`, then just assign `null` instead of `0`.

```
result.Add(new CompanyDetails() { 
    Name = dr["name"].ToString(), 
    City = dr["city"].ToString(), 
    StreetName = dr["streetName"].ToString(), 
    StreetNr = dr["apartmentNr"] == DBNull.Value ? (int?)null : (int)dr["apartmentNr"]
    Tax = dr["TAX"] == DBNull.Value ? (int?)null : (int)dr["TAX"]
    )});
```

Comment: Personally I'd say that is giving the incorrect result when the value is null; assuming, of course, that `Tax` allows nulls (`int?`)

Comment: yes, it's int? tax. In this app user can add this or not, this is optional, but I need to show all information even it's null

Comment: I agree, @MarcGravell, but I took the assumption that the OP doesn't want to handle `null` cases coz it's very common to ignore it and handle it on the output, since I don't see the OP's definition of CompanyDetails`. But, @Maggie, for the future, consider the use of nullable types, such as `int?`, which is the perfect map for integer database fields that allow nulls.

Comment: OK, @Maggie, then change the `0`s to `null`s in `StreetNr` and `Tax` above.

Comment: Sorry, I always tend to forget the casting; make it `(int?)null`

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
object tmp = dr["apartmentNr"];
int? apartmentNr = tmp is DBNull ? (int?)null : (int)tmp;
```

or easier - use a tool like "dapper" to avoid having to do all this stuff...

```
var row = conn.Query<CompanyDetails>("select * from ...", args).FirstOrDefault();
```

or:

```
var rows = conn.Query<CompanyDetails>("select * from ...", args).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this;

```
dr["TAX"] is DBNull ? string.Empty : dr["TAX"].ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably do like this:

```
StreetName = (dr["streetName"] + "")
```

This should give you an empty string if its null, and give you the string from the DB if it isn't.

Comment: Actually, the `dr["streetName"].ToString()` will be `DBNull.Value.ToString()`, which is already `""`; I suspect the problem is on the `Convert` line...

Comment: the problem is with streetNr and Tax which are integers